# How can I derive a class from an interface that has generics

Tags: c#, generics

I have this interface defined:

```
public interface IOwlAnnotation2<T1, T2, T3>
{
    T1 OwlAnnotation { get; set; }
    T2 OwlClass { get; set; }
    T3 AnnotationValue { get; set; }
}
```

Now I want to derive a class for it... so I write:

```
public class OwlAnnotation2 : IOwlAnnotation2<T1, T2, T3>
```

but I get errors of Cannot resolve symbol on T1,2,3 ...What is the correct way of deriving form that interface?

Comment: Finally you used my triple ;)

Comment: @SaeedAmiri : Lol yeah.. but that guy had written it an easier way that I cold copy-paste and run :) thanks tho.

Comment: I used CAPS on in mozila when I was writing the code, when you said is wrong, I again write it in VS and saw it's ok (but without CAPS), and I thought you are wrong ;)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to specify type parameters in the implementing class.  You can either keep them generic:

```
public class OwlAnnotation2<T1, T2, T3> : IOwlAnnotation2<T1, T2, T3>
```

or make them concrete:

```
public class OwlAnnotation2 : IOwlAnnotation2<string, int, bool>
```

Comment: The second example is not legal C# code.  I think you meant for the concrete types to be specified on the interface, not the class like this: `public class OwlAnnotation2 : IOwlAnnotation2<string, int, bool>`

Answer (score 4):

Either make the class generic with the same argument valence, or have it implement a version of the interface with the class arguments determined, depending upon which you really want.

You can mix and match too, if the class only determines some of the classes of the interface, but I'm imagining that's probably not the case given the question.